# how to calculate difference between two dates using java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

What would be the simplest way to find the difference between two java.util.Date objects in java. We are just interested in the days part alone (no minutes, seconds)

Note: We don't want to use the joda-time package as a dependency for this.