# Finding days difference in java

Tags: java, date

After consulting a few forums, I ended up using the code below to find the days difference. But, I see a problem with the logic (may be it's my over sight?). I see that for days difference between 11 to 14 and 11 to 15 is same. How is it possible?

```
Date createdDate = new Date((2013 + 1900), (1 + 1), 11);
Date expirationDate = new Date((2013 + 1900), (1 + 1), 11);
for (int i = 11; i < 20; i++) {
    expirationDate.setDate(i);

    System.out.println("11 to " + i + " = "
            + (int) (expirationDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime())
            / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

The output is:

```
11 to 11 = 0
11 to 12 = 1
11 to 13 = 2
11 to 14 = 3
11 to 15 = 3
11 to 16 = 4
11 to 17 = 5
11 to 18 = 6
11 to 19 = 7
```

Comment: Like the answer below suggests, you should use a Calendar in stead of a Date.  All the methods you're using are deprecated.

Comment: I also have to wonder if your strange output is related to the fact that you're comparing two dates from the year 3913!  To create a Calendar for Jan 11th, 2013 you would do this: `Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(1900 + 113, 2, 11);`

Comment: Should the year matter in case of days difference?

Comment: I have no idea... Calendars are a lot more complicated than they appear on the surface.  I won't even attempt to comment on what will happen with a calendar from 2000 years in the future!  **HOWEVER**, now that I look at your code again I see a possible error your code: you can't use an int to represent a timestamp (it's too small).  You need to use a long.  An integer is only large enough to represent 1 month in milliseconds.  This could certainly be the cause of your strange output.

Comment: You are correct. My intention was to get days as int. I should have been more careful with the brackets!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using float, I see the problem. Using timestamp doesn't  seem like a good approach to finding the days difference between 2 dates.

11 to 11 = 0.0
11 to 12 = 1.0
11 to 13 = 2.0
11 to 14 = 3.0
11 to 15 = 3.9583333
11 to 16 = 4.9583335
11 to 17 = 5.9583335
11 to 18 = 6.9583335
11 to 19 = 7.9583335

Going forward, I find the most conclusive way to determine the date difference as

```
Calendar cre_calendar = new GregorianCalendar((2013), (1), 11);
        Calendar exp_calendar = new GregorianCalendar((2013), (1), 19);
        Calendar maxDays = new GregorianCalendar(((2013)), (12), 31);

        if (exp_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < cre_calendar
                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            System.out
                    .println((exp_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + maxDays
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
                            - cre_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        } else {
            System.out.println((exp_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
                    - cre_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        }
```

Comment: Using timestamps **IS** the correct way to do it.  However, you need to use a `long` to represent a timestamp (not a float or int).  An integer is only large enough to capture one month of time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)'s [`Days#daysBetween()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29). There is no better way.

```
DateMidnight createdDate = new DateMidnight(2013, 2, 11);

for (int i = 11; i < 20; i++) {

    DateMidnight expirationDate = new DateMidnight(2013, 2, i);
    int dayDifference = Days.daysBetween(createdDate, expirationDate);

    System.out.println("11 to " + i + " = " + dayDifference);
}
```

Comment: I saw that in a different thread,but, I can't use a third party jar.

Comment: Beyond my comprehension! (Still trying to reason out why we can't use open licensed third party jars with my project team)

Answer (score 1):

[Date(year,day, month )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor is deprecated. i would simply use Calendars methods to get the difference between two days:

```
Calendar cal1=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2=Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(createdDate);
cal2.setTime(expirationDate);
System.out.println(cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH )-cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );
```

**EDIT:**

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(2013, 2, 11);
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(2013, 2, 11);
for (int i = 11; i < 20; i++) {
 cal2.set(Calendar.DATE, i);
    System.out.println("11 to " + i + " = " + (cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) -cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
11 to 11 = 0
11 to 12 = 1
11 to 13 = 2
11 to 14 = 3
11 to 15 = 4
11 to 16 = 5
11 to 17 = 6
11 to 18 = 7
11 to 19 = 8
```

Comment: Just a small note: you (and the OP) are creating dates in the year 3913.  I would guess that the current year (2013) is what you actually want...

Comment: While creating Calendar, we don't need the 1900 adjustment.

Comment: @jahroy iam not sure what OP wanted the year to be, tus i just copy pasted his date info .. :P

Answer (score 1):

`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` is wrong way to find day difference. You can use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) but there is a pure java solution.

Let we have two inialized variables

```java
Calendar firstDay = ...;
Calendar secondDay = ...;
```

and

```java
firstDay.before(lastDay)
```

is `true`.

Run

```java
int firstDayNo = firstDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int secondDayNo = secondDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int dayDifference, yearMultiplier;

dayDifference = -firstDayNo;
yearMultiplier = secondDay.get(Calendar.YEAR) - firstDay.get(Calendar.YEAR);
while (yearMultiplier > 0) {
    dayDifference += firstDay.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    firstDay.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    yearMultiplier--;
}
dayDifference += secondDayNo;

return dayDifference;
```

Comment: this wouldn't work from year to year though, would it?

Answer (score 0):

At least in the current version your code prints correct results

```
11 to 11 = 0
11 to 12 = 1
11 to 13 = 2
11 to 14 = 3
11 to 15 = 4
11 to 16 = 5
11 to 17 = 6
11 to 18 = 7
11 to 19 = 8
```

Nevertheless `new Date((2013 + 1900), (1 + 1), 11);` is incorrect, in fact it is `5813-03-01`. It should be `new Date((2013 - 1900), (1 - 1), 11);` see Date(int year, int month, int day) API

```
Parameters:
year - the year minus 1900.
month - the month between 0-11.
date - the day of the month between 1-31.
```