# java code to get the difference between two timestamp stored in arraylist

Tags: java

```
String sql = "SELECT  endtime FROM user_req";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

ArrayList<Timestamp> list1= new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
while (rs.next()) {

    list1.add(rs.getTimestamp("endtime"));
}
System.out.println("\n the requested time is : ");
System.out.println(list1);
```

this gives me the result:-

```
the requested time is : 
[2013-12-12 07:00:00.0, 2013-12-12 05:00:00.0]
```

this is the code which I've used that retrieves the timestamp data from MySQL and stores it in an aaraylist. but how to compare those dates and get the difference in terms of days and hours.
please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Will your query always return 2 results?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796841/getting-the-difference-between-date-in-days-in-java

Comment: Why not use `Timeslamp.comparteTo()`?

Comment: @shree.pat18  no..at present I have these 2 dates. I've seen many examples but I didn find any like how to compare more than one timestamp when it is stored in a single arraylist

Comment: @newuser : even in that example, they have a startdate and an enddate so that v can subtract..but my doubt is like how to perform samething when it is stored in a single arraylist... please help me with that concept

Comment: You do know how to get objects out of the list, right?

Comment: @sb15 - Have you bothered to read the javadoc for `ArrayList`?  Did you see the `get(int)` operation???

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    Collections.sort(timeStampList);
    Timestamp tempStamp = timeStampList.get(0);
    for (Timestamp startstamp : timeStampList)
    {
        if (tempStamp != startstamp)
        {
                long diffTime = startstamp.getTime() - tempStamp.getTime();
                diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60);

                if(diffDays > 24)
                {
                    System.out.println(diffDays / 24 +"Day" + " "+diffDays % 24 + "hours");
                }
                tempStamp = startstamp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the code.. I've tried with this nd its showing me the result as:-                                                      the requested time is : 
[2013-12-12 07:00:00.0, 2013-12-12 05:00:00.0]
7200000 83

Comment: thank you so much for the help..its working fine..just I had to make it in terms of hours, minutes nd seconds..which I could do :)

Comment: is it possible to apply the same logic if there are more than 2 timestamps in a list.. If so I thought of arranging it or sorting it in a ascending order and then check the difference. sorting I'm able to do.. so can I apply the same logic??

Comment: S its possible to show the difference for more than 2. If show the diff of 1,2 and 2,3 and 3,4 and so on.