# Not able to get difference between two datetime?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Please check the below code. I am trying to get the difference but every time getting 0.
Can anybody please point me what is the problem with below code?

```
SimpleDateFormat sDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy");
try {

    long d1 = sDateFormat.parse("10:04:00 04/04/2014").getTime();
    long d2 = sDateFormat.parse("10:09:00 04/04/2014").getTime();

    long difference = d2 - d1;

    Log.i(TAG,">> Difference = "+difference);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you ca also use joda api

Comment: ur d1 and d2 dates are same or different dates?

Comment: @Wizard, both are having different times

Comment: @Hitendra did u tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325117/java-android-calculate-days-between-2-dates-and-present-the-result-in-a-spec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your formatter does not fit the date format used.

Try:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

From Android Developer documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can see `M` is for `Month` and `m` is for `minute`...

```
M   month in year   (Text)      M:1 MM:01 MMM:Jan MMMM:January MMMMM:J
m   minute in hour  (Number)    30
```

So, you should change the date format from this...

```
hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy
```

to this...

```
hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy
```

I hope this format correction will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your format, `hh:mm:ss dd/mm/yyyy` has two problems:

1. `h` is used for 12-Hour time format i.e. a time format with AM/PM marker which is not the case with your date-time strings. You need to use `H` which is used for a 24-Hour time format.
2. `m` is not used for a month. For a month, you need to use `M`.

Apart from this, the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s d/M/u");
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("10:04:00 04/04/2014", dtf);
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("10:09:00 04/04/2014", dtf);
        long diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(start, end);
        System.out.println(diff);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
300000
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>